# can't import ui-select in angularjs and ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ui-select

I'm trying to import ui-select in my js file using yarn and webpack than import it in my module as follow.

```
import ngSanitize from 'angular-sanitize';
import uiselect from 'ui-select';
import 'ui-select/dist/select.css';

export default angular.module('app.module', [
/** ... **/
ngSanitize,
'ui.select'
/** ... **/
])
```

but When I check my generated css file I can see that the CSS was correctly imported however not the js.(there is no issue on my webpack config as I can see ngSanitize js codeon the generated vendor file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be correct following this [ui-select github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/692)

Would you share more details about your webpack.config.js file, may be you are generating it in another output file.